# I trained a model in torch and then convert it to caffe and after that to tf. How to convert it now to onnx?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, onnx, tf2onnx

I trained a Resnet model in torch.
Then, I converted it to caffe and to tflite.
now I want to convert it to onnx.
How can I do it?
I try that command:

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --tflite  resnet.lite --output resnet.lite.onnx --opset 13 --verbose
```

because the current format of the model is tflite,

and got that error:

```
return packer_type.unpack_from(memoryview_type(buf), head)[0]
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 11202612 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 11202608 (actual buffer size is 2408448)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can directly convert the model from PyTorch to onnx. Pytorch gives support for the same using `torch.onnx.export`  [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html)

Comment: Thanks @HirenNamera . I can not convert the model like this? When in TF format?

Comment: but you have pytorch model also with you right? which you had trained using pytorch you can use that model to convert to onnx.

Comment: No. I have torch model. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this checkout [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/tutorials/tensorflow-convert-model)
may be you need to freeze the model layers before starting conversion.

```
pip install onnxruntime
pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model ./checkpoints/yolov4.tf --output model.onnx --opset 11 --verbose
```

you can try this one also [link](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/tf-get-started.html)

```
pip install tf2onnx
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tf2onnx
import onnx

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="relu"))

input_signature = [tf.TensorSpec([3, 3], tf.float32, name='x')]
# Use from_function for tf functions
onnx_model, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, input_signature, opset=13)
onnx.save(onnx_model, "dst/path/model.onnx")
```

Comment: Thanks @Hiren Namera , but I don't ask about converting tf model, 
I already know that, I asking about a slightly more complex case. If you can answer what I asked - I would be happy. Good Day:)

Comment: Why are you converting tflite to onnx, you can convert tf or torch to onnx with int32 or int8. that will be the same as onnx convertion.

Comment: OK, I still have the same question- how do you convert torch model or torch model that I converted to tf, into onnx model?

Comment: Check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72557030/12635565)

Comment: You can check [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html) and [link2](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html)

Comment: You give me pytorch. I need torch. Its not the same

Comment: both are same send me model i will send script for convertion.

Comment: Hi @Hiren Namera, I found the bug, that was problem with the model file that not copied well:( :(. After solved it, the error I mentioned in my question was disappear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should try check your model file, maybe you have a wrong file, and that error is because of that.
try copy / download again the files and then try the tf conversion:

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --tflite  resnet.lite --output resnet.lite.onnx --opset 13 --verbose
```